# Is there a way to add the values present in an array in cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

I have got two arrays through the following cypher query

```
  return p.home,p1.away
    collect(distinct toInteger(p.score[0])) as value1,
    collect(distinct toInteger(p1.score[1])) as value2
```

Here, value1=[1,2,3,4]  and value=[3,0,6,2]
I wanted to have:

sum (1+2+3+4+3+0+6+2)  as totalValue ?

Comment: Does your use case really require you to sum `DISTINCT` scores?

Answer (score 0):

Is `distinct` a necessity? If it isn't, you can simply use:

```
RETURN sum(toInteger(p.score[0]) + toInteger(p1.score[1])) as value2
```

If you have to use `distinct` first, you can sum elements in arrays like this:

```
WITH
  [1, 2, 3, 4] AS value1, 
  [3, 0, 6, 2] AS value2
RETURN
  [i IN range(0, length(value1)-1) | value1[i] + value2[i]]
```

This uses the [`range`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-range) function to define a variable `i` that iterates on the arrays.

Note that `value1` and `value2` are not the best names: arrays should have a plural name (e.g. `values1`).

Comment: @GaborSzamyas In your first query, I believe you meant to use `SUM()` instead of `COLLECT()`.